# What is the difference between codelyzer and tslint?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

Can someone please guide me about the following questions:

1. What is the difference between **codelyzer** and **tslint**?
2. Are both used for code analysis **only**? If so, then which one is mostly **recommended**?
3. Are both **dependent** on each other?
4. Do we need both at the **same time** for any particular Angular 2+ project?

I'm so confused regarding both of these **npm package**s.

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer). The first sentence "A set of tslint rules for static code analysis of Angular TypeScript projects." answers 2, 3, 4, and probably 1.

Comment: @str thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Github repo](https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer) says it all :

> A set of tslint rules for static code analysis of Angular TypeScript projects.

So no they're not **both** dependent on each other.
Only Codelyzer relies on TsLint.

And yes you need both of them for your angular projects if you want to lint your code **OR** you can use only TsLint and set your own rules but it's not too much fun and I'd advise you to use Codelyzer ;)

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate your response. Link is helpful.  :)

Comment: how does codelyzer/tslint fit in with Angular CLI's `ng lint`?